# Static Compilation fails when using Maps

Tags: groovy

Compilation fails when we try to compile the following code using groovy 2.4.12 :

> Error is: [Static type checking] - Incompatible generic argument
>   types. Cannot assign java.util.Map  to: java.util.Map

This error is with the second function (tester()).

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
public class GroovyTest{

    public Map<String,String> testReturn() {
        def retString = [: ];
        retString.put("a","b");
        return retString;
    }
    public Map<String,String> tester() {
        def retString = [: ];
            retString = testReturn();
        return retString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work in Groovy 2.5.5

Comment: The same with 2.4.12 - it compiles without any error.

Comment: Sorry forgot something in the question. The real script where the issue is huge so I was trying to narrow it down. Forgot a key part of it. Edited with the latest one. This is the exact case which is failing.

Comment: Still works with 2.5.7.  It's great, if you reduce the problem, but please also make sure the problem is there. If you take this code, put it in a file, `groovyc` it, it works. Please make sure, to reduce the problem properly, so that other can reproduce the actual error